# "We prove a theorem that ..." or "We prove the theorem that ..."?

Tags: sentence-construction, articles

One of my papers proves a theorem. And in the abstract I want to introduce what I do in this paper, so I began with "We prove A theorem that ...". But then I was aware of this: Could it be "We prove THE theorem that ..."?

Which one is the correct one?

Comment: If it is an introduction, wouldn't you write "We *will* prove..."?

Answer (score 3):

I think it depends on whether the rest of your sentence *fully* or *only partly describes* the theorem. Compare:

> We prove the theorem that all cats enjoy Grieg

with

> We prove a theorem that shows the relationship between pet species and appreciation of Norwegian classical composers

In the first case it wouldn't make sense to say *a theorem* because there isn't more than one to choose from: you've exactly stated what the theorem is, so it's *the* theorem. In the second case there could be many theorems fitting that description, so it's *a*.

Comment: I agree with that. From wikipedia: "a theorem is a statement that has been proven on the basis of previously established statements, such as other theorems—and generally accepted statements, such as axioms." If you say "we prove a theorem about the relation between A and B" then "a" is correct, whereas if you say "we prove the theorem that B always follows from A" then "the" seems better.

Comment: I see what you meant. And the clause describing "theorem" is indeed partly describes the theorem that I proved, so right, using "a" is more legitimate than using "the". Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Since you're introducing the theorem to the reader, I believe you should use the indefinite article.

> We prove **a** theorem that...

Looking for examples at Google Books, I found dosens of instances using the indefinite article in similar contexts, such as:

> We prove **a** theorem stating that any semantics can be encoded as a compositional semantics, which means that, essentially, the standard definition of compositionality is formally vacuous. *(COLING-92: proceedings of the 15th International Conference on Computational Linguistics)*

or:

> In his 1857 paper, Kummer proved **a** theorem which assured that FLT holds for a certain class of irregular primes (see Lecture VII). *([13 Lectures on Fermat's Last Theorem, page 200](http://books.google.ru/books?id=w2o67-lBGhIC&lpg=PA200&dq=%22proved%20a%20theorem%20which%22&hl=ru&pg=PA200#v=onepage&q=%22proved%20a%20theorem%20which%22&f=false))*

Comment: Ah, appreciated. :) I see, I see.